# Override abstract Scala type

Tags: scala

I would like a method to override a type defined in an abstract class extended by another class.

Here is a simple example for illustration:

```
abstract class abstr_test{ def word: Int} 

class sub_test(s :String) extends abstr_test{def word: String = s}
```

Comment: An interface that has a member `word` with a type of `Int`, will enforce the signature on sub-classes.  Res ipsa loquitur this is not possible.

Comment: trait Test[A] { def word: A }
class StringTest(s: String) extends Test[String] { def word: String = s }

Comment: Thanks to all! Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type variable to accomplish this.

```
abstract class Test {
    type A
    def word: A
}

class SubTest(s: String) extends Test {
    type A = String
    def word: String = s
}
```

Comment: plus one; just to mention that: 1) `A` could be just a type parameter 2) `Test` could be a trait

Comment: Agreed, it could become `trait abstr_test[A]{ def word: A}`

Comment: Thanks to all, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain why allowing what you wanted (as opposed to what @soote's answer provides) would be a very bad idea.

Say you have a `val x: abstr_test` in scope of a method. Then you can do `val y: Int = x.word`. It doesn't matter where `x` came from; if you get to this line (and `x` isn't `null`, and the implementation of `word` doesn't throw an exception), then `y` must be an `Int`; otherwise, what would `def word: Int` even mean?

But if `sub_test` extends `abstr_test`, then a value of type `sub_test` is also a value of `abstr_test`; again, that's just the meaning of "subtype". So you actually can have `val x: abstr_test = new sub_test("not a number")`. What should be the value of `y` after `val y: Int = x.word`?